# How to get the initial default value for some object

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Hi I have bound my model as follows, which is working like charm but there's one scenario in which I want the default options back when I click on Cancel Button

[image: This is the scenario where I want default options]

```
var initialData;
$.getJSON("/ASPNET/Questionnaire/EditQuestionJSON/",
    function (d) {
        ko.applyBindings(new QuestionsModel(d));
    }
);

var QuestionsModel = function (Questions) {
    var self = this;
    self.Questions = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(Questions, function (q) {
        return { QuestionID: q.QuestionID, EnQuestion: q.EnQuestion, FrQuestion: q.FrQuestion, Options: ko.observableArray(q.Options) };
    }));

    self.addQuestion = function () {
        self.Questions.push({
            QuestionID: "",
            EnQuestion: "",
            FrQuestion: "",
            Options: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };

    self.removeQuestion = function (question) {
        self.Questions.remove(question);
    };

    self.addOption = function (question) {
        question.Options.push({
            QuestionOption: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeOption = function (question) {
        $.each(self.Questions(), function () { this.Options.remove(question) })
    };

    self.save = function () {
        //self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.Questions), null, 2));
        console.log(ko.toJS(self.Questions));
    };

    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};
```

2nd Problem I've is: When I am clicking onto the edit button for each question , After first time it shows

Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

When I tried to resolve this using ko.cleanNode

another problem arises that next time my each option is apearing 4 times and next time nothing happens

Did you get the question or I need to add more detail to it?

Comment: There is no "easy" way to do what you want. You can have an `javascript` object holding all your `default values`. And when the user clicks the cancel button you can update the `viewmodel` with the defualt values.

Comment: You could just reload the form on cancel (from template or server)